Ошибка: "The name 'Keys' does not exist in the current context"
У меня почему-то не находит имя Keys. Я скачал через менеджер NuGet следующие пакеты:

InputSimulation;
System.Drawing.Common.

Мой код:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    // Настройки
    static int pixelBox = 3;
    static int pixelSens = 40;
    static Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(254, 254, 64); // Жëлтый
    static int tapTime = 74;
    static int waitTime = 0;
    static int clicks = 1;
    static bool waiting = false;
    static bool noMovementCheck = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Основной цикл
        while (true)
        {
            if (IsKeyDown(Keys.Alt)) // Проверка на удержание ALT
            {
                HoldMode();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsKeyDown(object alt)
    {
        // Какая-то логика
    }

    private static void HoldMode()
    {
        var keys = new[] { Keys.W, Keys.A, Keys.D, Keys.S, Keys.Space };
        bool allKeysNotPressed = true;
    }
}

Но возникает ошибка:

CS0103    Имя "Keys" не существует в текущем контексте.

Что ещё можно сделать?

А вы уверены, что должно быть Keys, а не KeyCode? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

@CrazyElf https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys

@aepot Я почему-то решил, что вопрос про Unity 3D )

Что за COMReference? Для чего это? Предполагаю, это были неудачные опыты и это надо удалить. Кстати, при использовании Windows.Forms устанавливать пакет System.Drawing.Common не требуется.

Вам нужно использовать ConsoleKey в консольном приложении, например: if (ConsoleKeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape), а не ваши пространства имён, которые вы указали, но у вас в вопросе есть более глубокая проблема — для решения смотрите мой ответ

У вас в коде есть строка static Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(254, 254, 64);  — вы уверены, что вам нужно работать с цветами в консольном приложении?

Мне кажется, стоит переквалифицировать вопрос в "Как использовать Alt в консольном приложении?".

И, пожалуйста, прикладывайте код в вопросе, а не скрины

@aepot А тут как с лицензией? (правка скрина) Если это так, то стоит про это где либо упомянуть и поговорить с человеком.

Считывать клавишу Alt без сочетания с другой клавишей — не очень удачная затея, поскольку в консольном приложении сделать это довольно проблематично.
Вот как вы можете поступить:
Вариант 1 — считывать комбинацию клавиши и Alt
Вы можете ожидать от пользователя нажатия комбинации клавиш Alt + любая другая клавиша. Для этого нужно изменить код следующим образом:
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите на комбинацию \"Alt + любая клавиша\" (для выхода нажмите Esc)...");

            ConsoleKeyInfo ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (ConsoleKeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                break;
            }

            if ((ConsoleKeyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Нажата клавиша Alt вместе с " + ConsoleKeyInfo.Key);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Нажата клавиша " + ConsoleKeyInfo.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}

Вариант 2 — проверять состояние Alt по таймеру
Вы можете проверять нажатось клавиши Alt в реальном времени с помощью таймера:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    const int VK_MENU = 0x12; // код клавиши Alt

    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите Alt (для выхода нажмите Esc)...");

        Timer Timer = new(CheckAltKey, null, 0, 100); // Проверка каждые 100 миллисекунд

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CheckAltKey(object? state)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вы нажали клавишу Alt!");
        }
    }
}

